# Sort FileA into FileB while actively removing lines from FileA

Tags: awk

I tried simplifying the title, apologies if it's somewhat confusing.

I have a large text file (File A)(around 13GB) and I want to sort through it (into File B) to delete duplicate lines. Problem is I have a limited amount of space, so I can't create a file around the same size. Is there a way to actively delete lines that are sorted from File A?

My sort code: `awk ' !x[$0]++' FileA.lst > FileB.lst`

Comment: Seems he found the answer by himself.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple answer: consecutive duplicate lines

For in-place editing, `sed` is the tool of choice. To remove consecutive duplicate lines, use this:

```
 sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

### Not so simple: non-consecutive duplicate lines

If the duplicate lines are non-consecutive, you can use this -- but there's a risk of overflowing buffer space:

```
 sed -n 'G; s/\n/&&/; /^\([ -~]*\n\).*\n\1/d; s/\n//; h; P'
```

Because `sort` uses the merge sort algorithm (assuming the GNU `sort` usually used on Linux), the risk of running out of memory or disk remains, because merge sort can use a lot of auxiliary space in worst-case situations. Aside from that risk, @thom is correct suggesting `sort -u`.

If the problem is to remove non-consecutive duplicate lines, and there's a risk that `sed` or an in-place `sort` might run out of space due to a worst-case situation, the best solution is probably to move the file to some sort of external storage, such as a USB flash drive.

Note that if you don't *know* whether `sed` or `sort` might run out of space and corrupt your file, you really want to back up the file, one way or another. Another solution might be to sort through your filesystem for large files that can stand to be compressed, and compress enough of them to do the `awk '!x[$0]++' inFile > outFile` or `sort -u` safely, into a separate file. Then you don't lose data if the command fails.

See also "Useful one-line scripts for `sed`": http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the program  `sort` can sort 'inplace', that means that you can use the same file for input as for output. `sort -u` will remove duplicate lines.

the command would be:

```
sort -u mylargefile mylargefile
```

It might, of course, be advisable to test it first on a smaller test file before you start doing the real thing. Especially if you don't have a backup of that 13 GB file